# Stuck in an if statement in a while loop. How do i exit?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

i wrote the following code to iteratively build a matrix depending on the conditions met. But i'm stuck in the 2nd if statement. for some reason it doesnt move to else and prints the contents of my print statements over and over, infinitely.

```
B=np.empty([u,v])               
for i in range(u):
    for j in range(v):
        B[i][j]=0  

vi= df['GroupId'][0]
G_df= pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, v), columns=['j', 'vi']) 
G_df['j'][0] = 0
G_df['vi'][0] = 0
j=0
i=0
old_tweet_id=1
new_tweet_id=1
value= df['TFIDF_score'][0]

while i<u:
    old_tweet_id=new_tweet_id
    while (old_tweet_id == new_tweet_id):
        if j < v:
            new_js= [G_df.loc[G_df['vi'] == vi, 'j'].item()] 
            if new_js != 0:
                print('new_js',new_js)
                new_j= int(''.join(str(x) for x in new_js))
                print('new_j', new_j)
                B[i][new_j] = value         
                print('matrix', B)                
            else: 
                G_df.loc[-1]=[j,vi]
                B[i][j]=value
                vi = vi +1
                j=j+1
            if j>=v:
                old_tweet_id =  u +10
            else:
                cc = df['tweet_id'][j:j + 1]
                dd = df['TFIDF_score'][j:j + 1]
                value = dd[j]
                new_tweet_id = cc[j]

    i = i + 1
```

I tried using break and also tried to empty the new_js and new_j variables just before the else line but that didn't work either. 
I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't place my finger on it.

EDIT: 
I am trying to build a matrix from a dataframe of several columns one of the dataframe columns contains what i will use for the labels of my matrix column and a couple of them are repeating, so i used df.groupy to group the overlapping entries and assign an index to them so that all similar entries would have the same index value. These index values are stored in another dataframe column called GroupId. So while building the matrix, the values of the matrix itself are the df[TFIDF scores] and they will be inputted to the matrix based on a which column and row they belong to. where my problem arises from is while checking to see if a column label has been encountered and this current encounter is an overlap, so we need to use the first occurrence of the column label instead of creating a new column for it. I created a new dataframe (G_df) where it appends all the column labels it encountered and also where it compares the current column label to see if there is an existing one.

I know this is a lot but i've tried everything I know. I've been stuck at this problem for a long time.

Comment: If it's the `new_js` if: that will always trigger, since a list will always be different from zero. PS: All those conditions need no parentheses in Python and look more like C that way.

Comment: What is the value of u, when it enters the outer while loop?

Comment: @Amit u and v and re rows and column of the matrix. they were declared at the beginning of the code not shown here. but they are very large integer values.

Comment: @guidot I'm not quite sure i follow. Yes, im referring to the new_js if statement. Ii changed it to if len(new_js) != 0: and it didnt work, i also tried If new_js != [] and that didnt work either.

Comment: If your test condition j<v will fail, the loop is never going to end. You increment j at only one place and v is never updated. Could that be the reason? I am sorry, I have seen your cose in a hurry.

Comment: `if len(new_js)` or simply `if new_js` should work nevertheless, so the contents of new_js additionally seems to deviate from what you expect. Your identifiers are unfortunately not helpful to derive what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Amit j<v hasn't failed yet. It will be valid for a long time. Also, i don't update v because it contains the length of the column of the matrix, so I'm using that condition to ensure the size of the matrix doesn't exceed its intended size. Does the indentation of the if j>=v : line look right to you?

Comment: @guidot new_js was originally an integer but I kept getting errors about only being able to convert an array of size 1 to a python scalar, that's why I put it in a list and then transformed the list to an integer. I will edit my question to fully explain what I am trying to achieve. thanks

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. You're asking us about X (e.g. why your `if` always gets matched). That seems pretty trivial, `new_js` is a one-element list, and that's never going to be equal to `0`, so the `!=` condition is always true. But your real problem is Y, some pandas indexing thing I don't understand. You really need to focus your question on that, as you won't be very satisfied with an answer that's only about the `if` statement, and I'm not sure you've given enough information about your pandas stuff for even somebody who knows that library well to help you.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, i realized the whole setup was problematic so i rephrased my solution. I used the contents of the GroupId as the column labels of the matrix. I do not need to create another dataframe for comparison anymore. Therefore i dont run into that continuous loop anymore. Thanks